# Samsung EVO microSDXC (128GB, Class 10) writespeed 150kb/s

Tags: android, performance, copy, sd-card

I am copying milions of files (30kb each) to the microSD card (with fastcopy) from my SSD. at the beginning it was copying with ~1.5 MB/s. now it is down to a steady 0.15 MB/s (after 20gb).

File system is exFAT, allocation unit size is 8kb. The card is connected trough a USB 2.0 adapter to the PC. Card and adapter are cooled with an external fan.

(ca. every 1h the pc loses connection to the sd card and i have to run chkdsk.)

[CrystalDiskMark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Xa3.jpg) (situation right now)

how can i improve my situation? right now it would take me 6 days to copy all my data..

Answer (score 0):

It's normal when you want to copy plenty of files ， you can try these ways:

1.you  can compress this files to  one file , copy it to your card  and then uncompress it .

2.Copy thousands of files everytime .

According to your picture, When you copy millions of little files , It matched 4K - Write sheets , and with the time goes on , the speed slowed because dirty data needed to be recycled.

Comment: how would you go about 1? tried with 7-zip. it extracts to a temp folder in c: and then copies to the microSD.

Comment: Yes，you are right , I forgot this . you can try rsync to copy it , or owncloud...